# how to pass database error from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, error-handling, voting

I have something like voting database, so I made my database like this
Vote_table:

```
user_id
product_id
vote
primary key is both user_id & product_id
```

so that no one can vote for a product twice, and this is my model:

```
public function add_vote_records($product_id, $user_id)
{
    $this->db->set('product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->set('members_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->insert('product_votes');
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    return FALSE;

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
if ($this->products_model->add_vote_records($product_id, $user_id)) {
    $this->product($product_id);
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Sorry you already voted.');
    $this->product($product_id);
}
```

but it gives me this error when im trying to vote when I already voted:

> Duplicate entry '8-2' for key 'PRIMARY'

And that's what I really want, but I want to give the user another message my own message instead of this error.

Comment: Flash data only works on redirect();

Comment: This is because you model code is not correctly checking this member has already voted so the insert in the model is causing an error

Comment: Thanks @wolfgang1983 , it's not about flash data it's about why the model won't return false when it cant insert data.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly you are right, but how can I check this?

Comment: First do a query to see if this member has an entry for this product. Or test the result of your existing query for this error and assume its because they already voted